# How to drop a Clustered Index on a table if it exists and add a new Clustered Index?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

I am creating Clustered Index on a table and Dropping if it already exists.

I am using this Query.

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS CLX_Enrolment_StudentID_BatchID
ON Enrollment
CREATE INDEX CLX_Enrolment_StudentID_BatchID
ON Enrollment(Studentid, BatchId ASC);
```

Now,I want to know which Cluster is getting created here:-
Is this a Clustered or Non-Clustered?

```
CREATE INDEX CLX_Enrolment_StudentID_BatchID
ON Enrollment(Studentid, BatchId ASC);
```

Because on using:-

```
DROP clustered INDEX IF EXISTS CLX_Enrolment_StudentID_BatchID
ON Enrollment
```

I am getting this error:-

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'clustered'.
```

And,If I use:-

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS CLX_Enrolment_StudentID_BatchID
ON Enrollment
go
CREATE clustered INDEX CLX_Enrolment_StudentID_BatchID
ON Enrollment(Studentid, BatchId ASC);
```

I am getting this error:-

```
Cannot create more than one clustered index on table 'Enrollment'. Drop the existing clustered index 'PK__enrollme__DE799CE1E4649295' before creating another.
```

Now,I want to know in my Second Query which Index is getting created. And, If none of both is getting created then how to remove Clustered Index if it exists and create a new one.

Comment: Since the existing clustered index is the primary key index, you need to use to use `ALTER TABLE...DROP CONSTRAINT` and `ALTER TABLE...ADD CONSTRAINT` to change the existing primary key index to nonclustered before creating the new clustered index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `IF EXISTS` syntax to check `sys.indexes` table whether contains the index.

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM sys.indexes 
    WHERE name='CLX_Enrolment_StudentID_BatchID' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('Enrollment')
)
BEGIN
    DROP INDEX CLX_Enrolment_StudentID_BatchID ON [dbo].[Enrollment]
END
GO

CREATE clustered INDEX CLX_Enrolment_StudentID_BatchID
ON Enrollment(Studentid, BatchId ASC);
```

But I think there is an index `PK__enrollme__DE799CE1E4649295` on your table from your error message.

**Modify**

If you want to `DROP` PK or Clustered index automatically, you can try to use dynamic sql to create the script and use `sp_executesql` to exec that.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500),
        @TableName VARCHAR(50) = 'Enrollment',
        @Para NVARCHAR(500)='@TableName VARCHAR(50)'

SELECT @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',@TableName,' DROP CONSTRAINT ',name)
FROM sys.indexes 
WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(@TableName) AND type_desc = 'CLUSTERED' AND is_primary_key = 1
EXEC sp_executesql @sql,@Para,@TableName

SELECT @sql = CONCAT('DROP INDEX ',name,' ON dbo.',@TableName)
FROM sys.indexes 
WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(@TableName) AND type_desc = 'CLUSTERED'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,@Para,@TableName
```

> if your table already contains `PK` you need to use `ALTER TABLE .... DROP CONSTRAINT` instead of `drop index`.

Comment: I think while creating table I have added both StudentId and BatchId as Primary_Key. So, that might be a reason that it is showing-- Drop the existing clustered index 'PK__enrollme__DE799CE1E4649295' before creating another or anything else?

Comment: In my Index Descripton it is showing:-- clustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY

Comment: @SumitTiwary ok I edit my answer if your table already contains `PK` you need to use `ALTER TABLE .... DROP CONSTRAINT` instead of `drop index`.